# count(*) doesn't work when executing reader

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm trying to fetch all information from one table and count(*) from another.

Here's my c# code:

```
BlogCat = new List<BlogCategory>();

try
{
    using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnStr"].ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT c.*, count(pc.id) as 'total' FROM blogcategories c JOIN blogpostcat pc ON pc.cid = c.id", connection))
        using (OdbcDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                BlogCat.Add(new BlogCategory((int)dr["id"], (int)dr["parent"], dr["name"].ToString(), (int)dr["total"]));
            }
            dr.Close();
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

When I run this on MySQL it shows me exactly the result I want, but when I execute here it doesn't add anything to the object.

```
SELECT c.*
     , count(pc.id)   AS 'total' 
  FROM blogcategories c 
  JOIN blogpostcat    pc 
    ON pc.cid = c.id
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: you have to use SqlClient for it not oledb

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? Are your field names correct? `total` is the only name you explicitly define in your select.

Comment: It's also worth noting you don't need to call `Close` on `dr` or `connection` as that will be handled by your `using` statements.

Comment: @Dhaval Patel: He's using Odbc, not OleDb.

Comment: I got the exception Specified cast is not valid. (0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your SQL-String is not the same as the one you execute in MySQL.

```
SELECT c.*, count(pc.id) as 'total' 
FROM blogcategories c 
JOIN blogpostcat pc ON pc.cid = c.id
```

there is no group by, and yet you use the aggregate function count(pc.id) but also query other fields.
The syntax is simply wrong. 
Look at your code. 
You have a try-catch around your C# routine and don't log the error ...

Try

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

for a change.

You should also check that the connection state is not open before you do

```
connection.Open();
```

(pooling)

The same is true for

```
connection.Close();
```

Also try

```
System.Convert.ToInt32(dr["your_field"])
```

instead of

```
(int)dr["your_field"]
```

and I'd also use

```
System.Convert.ToString(dr["name"])
```

instead of

```
dr["name"].ToString()
```

Comment: I got the exception Specified cast is not valid. (0)

Comment: @bramalho: Try System.Convert.ToInt32(dr["your_field"]) instead of (int)dr["your_field"].

Comment: yes it works, thank you. Why it doesn't work with the simple (int)?

Comment: @bramalho: Because it does not return int. It either returns long, signed integer or double/numeric/float/decimal or a varchar OR NULL (System.DbNull.Value).